# Getting information for get form via javascript prompt

Tags: javascript

```
*

<form id="5" form method="get" action="http://crimson-craft.buycraft.net/checkout/packages">
    <input type="hidden" name="direct" value="true">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add">
    <input type="hidden" name="package" value="1250806">
    <input type="hidden" name="ign" value=username>
</form>
<script>
    function buynow5() {  
    var username = prompt("Please enter your MineCraft username", "");  
    if (username != null) {
            document.getElementById("5").submit();
        }
    }
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="buynow5()" class="sign_up radius3">Buy Now</a>
```

*

So the java-script popup works and asks for a input, then submits the form, but the form doesn't pass the variable. I'm sorry if this a dumb question, but I'm very new to this.

Comment: You need to check how forms work, you can't assign the `value` attribute to a variable and expect it to send. You need to save the `username` var value to a form input, then submit.

Answer (score 0):

## Fix:

Change this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ign" value=username>
```

to this:

```
<input id="usernameInput" type="hidden" name="ign" value="">
```

Then update your method like so:

```
function buynow5() {  
    var username = prompt("Please enter your MineCraft username", "");  
    if (username) {
        document.getElementById('usernameInput').value = username;
        document.getElementById('5').submit();
    }
}
```

You can't bind javascript properties to HTML inputs without extra libraries.

## Tip:

While you can make this work without any libraries, I highly suggest you look in to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to facilitate DOM manipulation and interactive events. If you want more control and databinding, take a look at [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) as well.

## Full Code:

```
<form id="5" form method="get" action="http://crimson-craft.buycraft.net/checkout/packages">
    <input type="hidden" name="direct" value="true">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add">
    <input type="hidden" name="package" value="1250806">
    <input id="usernameInput" type="hidden" name="ign" value="">
</form>
<script>
    function buynow5() {  
    var username = prompt("Please enter your MineCraft username", "");  
    if (username) {
            document.getElementById('usernameInput').value = username;
            document.getElementById("5").submit();
        }
    }
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="buynow5()" class="sign_up radius3">Buy Now</a>
```